# Read Manifest file in Spring boot application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, manifest, manifest.mf

We are using Spring-boot to build micro-services. In my project set-up we have a common maven module named **platform-boot** with main class with annotation `SpringBootApplication`

If we want to create a new micro-service (say **Service-1**), we simply add a dependency of **platform-boot** module and provide the **main-class** path in `pom.xml` and we are good to go.

Problem is when I try to read `Manifest.MF` file of **Service-1** by writing code in my 'main-class' in dependent module. It reads the `Manifest.MF` file of **platform-boot**.

Below is the code snippet of how I am reading `Manifest.MF` file in my main class.

```
MyMain.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
//Returns the path of MyMain.class which is nested jar
```

Please suggest a way to read the `Manifest.MF` file of **Service-1**.

PS: I want to read the `Maifest.MF` file to get *Implementation-Version*. Please suggest if any other way of getting it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two ways to solve this problem:

1. We can use **maven-dependency-plugin** to unpack the child jar while
   executing the phase `prepare-package`. This plug in will extract the
   class file from my **platform-boot** jar to my **Service-1**.

   ```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpack</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>my.platform</groupId>
              <artifactId>platform-boot</artifactId>
              <type>jar</type>
              <overWrite>false</overWrite>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
              <includes>**/*.class,**/*.xml,**/*.text</includes>
              <excludes>**/*test.class</excludes>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
          <includes>**/*.java, **/*.text</includes>
          <excludes>**/*.properties</excludes>
          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. Second approach is much simpler, in **spring-boot-maven-plugin** add a goal 
   `build-info`. This will write a file `build-info.properties` in your META-INF folder and is accessible in code as below.

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <goals>
                   <goal>build-info</goal>
                   <goal>repackage</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

   In your main method you can get this information using the BuildProperties 
   bean already registered in ApplicationContext.

   ```
   ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   BuildProperties properties = ctx.getBean(BuildProperties.class);
   ```

   In fact, Spring-actuator also uses this `BuildProperties` to get the build 
   information which is helpful in monitoring.

Comment: How to create 'build-info' with gradle

Answer (score 1):

Hi could you please elaborate the need of reading your service-1manifest.mf ?

If you just want the service1 as a dependeny in your parent common module and should not conflict with your service1 bootable application , you can do generate two jars through the exec configuration in spring-boot-maven-plugin .

Comment: I need to extract the `Implementation-Version` from `Manifest.MF` of Service-1 for logging purpose.

I have tried `${application.version}` provided by spring to read the `Implementation-Version` from `Manifest.MF` But it reads the version from 'platform-boot' where `MyMain` class resides.

Comment: @jack, Have you managed to read 'Implementation-Version' from application specific MANIFEST.MF file?